# Help with a riddle

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, puzzle

I want an NPC to give some indications to the party (without lying), but I want these indications to be misleading at first sight, so that they by following what they understood, get to a wrong. I also want to place a hint somewhere, that helps them understand the real meaning of the initial indications in an easier way.

The setting is your classic high fantasy world, haven't decided for a specific kind of place yet so mountains, sea, forest, whatever are fine

Comment: Welcome to the stack and please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate. Unfortunately, I think your question is way too broad as there can be a lot of different ways to answer this 'correctly' and that's not generally how we work. We do have a list of [recommended forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) which may be better suited for you, or you can earn enough rep (20) to join our [chat]. You may also want to decide if this is 5e or pathfinder.

Comment: Maybe tell us what you have so far?

Comment: We could potentially help finish something if you have it nearly completed (although a Forum is probably still a better way to crowdsource riddles/plot threads)